# How can I build an android application with an old api (as 16)?

Tags: android, permissions

For a personal use I would like to be able to call “Settings.System” (toggle 4g, toggle airplane mode…).

I understood that it’s not possible since API 17, when Settings.System became Settings.Global…
So, I started an application with API 16, but it still doesn’t work, I’m not allowed to toggle airplane mode.

Any tips to fix this problem? Or android liberties have been fully deprecated?

EDIT--
Here the few lines (kotlin) who do nothing:

```
try {
    val isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
        contentResolver,
        Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,
        0
    ) == 1
    Settings.System.putInt(
        contentResolver,
        Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,
        if (isEnabled) 0 else 1
    )
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)
    intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "exception:$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

And the result is:

```
exception:java.lang.SecurityException:
Permission Denial: not
allowed to send broadcast
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
from pid=18122, uid=10335
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you've tried and share code / errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `targetSdkVersion` to 16 in your `build.gradle` file.

If `targetSdkVersion`   is lower than Android's system version, then it applies a compatibility mode (which allows to call old API's).

Comment: Hi, thank you, I put the targetSdkVersion to 16, but it still doesn't work